# Angular como carregar uma lista antes de tudo

Tags: angular

Gostaria de uma ajuda se alguém já usou este componente: Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table'; o que acontece, eu estou tentando vir com a lista preenchida logo de começo, mas não está dando certo, o porque, eu estou identificando que isso acontece, porque ele só carrega a lista no meio do caminho depois que já tentou carregar algumas coisas do Ng2Table e aí a lista estando vazia ainda, começa a dar pau em algumas funções, por causa disso a questão é como carregar a lista antes de tudo sem ele ir pra frente sem tentar carregar outras coisas.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { BordaService } from "../borda.service";
import { Borda } from "../borda";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Ng2TableModule } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';
import { NgTableComponent, NgTableFilteringDirective, NgTablePagingDirective, NgTableSortingDirective } from 'ng2-table/ng2-table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-borda-list',
  templateUrl: './borda-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./borda-list.component.css'],
  providers: [BordaService]
})
export class BordaListComponent implements OnInit {
  public rows:Array<any> = [];
  public columns:Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Código', name: 'borda.codigoBorda'},
    {title: 'Borda', name: 'borda.nomeBorda', filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by name'}},
    {title: 'Descrição', name: 'borda.descricaoBorda'},
    {title: 'Valor', name: 'borda.valorBorda'}
  ];
  public page:number = 1;
  public itemsPerPage:number = 10;
  public maxSize:number = 5;
  public numPages:number = 1;
  public length:number = 0;

  public config:any = {
    paging: true,
    sorting: {columns: this.columns},
    filtering: {filterString: ''},
    className: ['table-striped', 'table-bordered']
  };

  bordas : Borda[];
  private data:Array<any> = this.bordas;

  public constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private bordaService: BordaService,
    private toastr: ToastrService) {

    this.getAllBordas();
  }

  public ngOnInit():void {
    this.onChangeTable(this.config);
    this.length = this.bordas.length;
  }

  public changePage(page:any, data:Array<any> = this.data):Array<any> {
    let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
    let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : data.length;
    return data.slice(start, end);
  }

  public changeSort(data:any, config:any):any {
    if (!config.sorting) {
      return data;
    }

    let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
    let columnName:string = void 0;
    let sort:string = void 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      if (columns[i].sort !== '' && columns[i].sort !== false) {
        columnName = columns[i].name;
        sort = columns[i].sort;
      }
    }

    if (!columnName) {
      return data;
    }

    // simple sorting
    return data.sort((previous:any, current:any) => {
      if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }

  public changeFilter(data:any, config:any):any {
    let filteredData:Array<any> = data;
    this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
      if (column.filtering) {
        filteredData = filteredData.filter((item:any) => {
          return item[column.name].match(column.filtering.filterString);
        });
      }
    });

    if (!config.filtering) {
      return filteredData;
    }

    if (config.filtering.columnName) {
      return filteredData.filter((item:any) =>
        item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));
    }

    let tempArray:Array<any> = [];
    filteredData.forEach((item:any) => {
      let flag = false;
      this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
        if (item[column.name].toString().match(this.config.filtering.filterString)) {
          flag = true;
        }
      });
      if (flag) {
        tempArray.push(item);
      }
    });
    filteredData = tempArray;

    return filteredData;
  }

  public onChangeTable(config:any, page:any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}):any {
    if (config.filtering) {
      Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
    }

    if (config.sorting) {
      Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
    }

    let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
    let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
    this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
    this.length = sortedData.length;
  }

  public onCellClick(data: any): any {
    console.log(data);
  }

  getAllBordas() {
    this.bordaService.findAll()
      .subscribe(
        bordas => {
          this.bordas = bordas;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Solução Completa:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { BordaService } from "../borda.service";
import { Borda } from "../borda";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { PaginationConfig } from 'ng2-bootstrap/pagination/pagination.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-borda-list',
  templateUrl: './borda-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./borda-list.component.css'],
  providers: [BordaService, PaginationConfig]
})
export class BordaListComponent {

  public rows:Array<any> = [];

  public columns:Array<any> = [
    {title: 'Código', name: 'codigoBorda'},
    {title: 'Borda', name: 'nomeBorda', filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filtrar Pela Borda'}},
    {title: 'Descrição', name: 'descricaoBorda'},
    {title: 'Valor', name: 'valorBorda'},
    {title: 'Ativa', name: 'bordaAtiva'},
    {title: '', name: 'acaoAlterar', sort:false, className: 'accepter-col-action'},
    {title: '', name: 'acaoExcluir', sort:false, className: 'accepter-col-action'}
  ];

  acaoEditar : string = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" (click)="editBordaPage(borda)">Editar</button>';
  acaoExcluir : string = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" (click)="deleteBorda(borda)">Deletar</button>';

  public page:number = 1;
  public itemsPerPage:number = 10;
  public maxSize:number = 5;
  public numPages:number = 1;
  public length:number = 0;

  public config:any = {
    paging: true,
    sorting: {columns: this.columns},
    filtering: {filterString: ''},
    className: ['table table-striped', 'table-bordered']
  };

  bordas : Borda[] = new Array;
  data: Array<any>;

  //
  codigoBorda : number;
  loginUsuarioParam : string;

  public constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private bordaService: BordaService,
    private toastr: ToastrService) {

    this.getAllBordas();
  }

  public changePage(page:any, data:Array<any> = this.data):Array<any> {
    let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
    let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : data.length;
    return data.slice(start, end);
  }

  public changeSort(data:any, config:any):any {
    if (!config.sorting) {
      return data;
    }

    let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
    let columnName:string = void 0;
    let sort:string = void 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      if (columns[i].sort !== '' && columns[i].sort !== false) {
        columnName = columns[i].name;
        sort = columns[i].sort;
      }
    }

    if (!columnName) {
      return data;
    }

    // simple sorting
    return data.sort((previous:any, current:any) => {
      if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
        return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
  }

  index : number = 0;

  public changeFilter(data:any, config:any):any {
    let filteredData:Array<any> = data;
    this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
      if (column.filtering) {
        filteredData = filteredData.filter((item:any) => {
          return item[column.name].match(column.filtering.filterString);
        });
      }
    });

    if (!config.filtering) {
      return filteredData;
    }

    if (config.filtering.columnName) {
      return filteredData.filter((item:any) =>
        item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));
    }

    let tempArray:Array<any> = [];
    filteredData.forEach((item:any) => {
      let flag = false;
      this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
        if (item[column.name].toString().match(this.config.filtering.filterString)) {
          flag = true;
        }
      });
      if (flag) {
        tempArray.push(item);
      }
    });
    filteredData = tempArray;

    return filteredData;
  }

  public onChangeTable(config:any, page:any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}):any {
    if (config.filtering) {
      Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
    }

    if (config.sorting) {
      Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
    }

    let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
    let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
    this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
    this.length = sortedData.length;
  }

  public onCellClick(data: any): any {

    if (data.column == "acaoAlterar") {
      this.editBordaPage(data.row);
    } else if (data.column == "acaoExcluir") {
      this.deleteBorda(data.row);
    }
  }

  getAllBordas() {
    this.bordaService.findAll()
      .subscribe(
        bordas => {
          this.bordas = bordas;
          for (let borda of this.bordas) {
            borda.acaoAlterar = this.acaoEditar;
            borda.acaoExcluir = this.acaoExcluir
            ;
          }

          this.data = this.bordas;
          this.length = this.bordas.length;
          this.onChangeTable(this.config);
        }
      );
  }

  redirectNewBordaPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/borda/create']);
  }

  editBordaPage(borda: Borda) {
    if (borda) {
      this.router.navigate(['/borda/edit', borda.codigoBorda]);
    }
  }

  deleteBorda(borda: Borda) {
    if (borda) {
      this.bordaService.deleteBordaById(borda.codigoBorda)
      .subscribe (
        data => {
          if (data.status == 200) {
            this.getAllBordas();
            this.toastr.success("Borda", "Borda Excluída Com Sucesso.");
          }
        },
        error => {
          if (error.status == 0) {
            this.toastr.error("Borda", "Sem Conexão Com O WebService."); 
          } else if (error.status == 500) {
            this.toastr.error("Borda", "Não Foi Possível Deletar O Registro.");
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: quais erros estão acontecendo?

Comment: resolvido e colocado a solução.